# why physical memory NOT contiguous?

Tags: linux, memory, unix, virtual-memory

Background: I was running a kernel module that give me some info about kernel virtual address space which told me that Linux lowmem region is approximately 7.24 GB. lowmem region is supposed to be a 1:1 mapping to physical memory at a specific fixed offset. so if system RAM is 6 GB then lowmem region is supposed to be also 6 GB.

so I'm running ubuntu 20.04 64-bit OS with 6 GB of RAM instead of getting lowmem region size of 6 I got 7.24 gigabytes which I cant see why so I asked this question on stack exchange unix&linux [LINK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/648086/linux-report-that-lowmem-region-is-more-than-physical-memory-available/648295#648295) and got an answer that physical memory is not contiguous which I asked how but didnt get an answer so I asked this question here because this site is more targeted toward hardware. so In a nutshell why physical memory is not contiguous and have holes in it that make it extend to past address mark of 6 GB.

Comment: It's not a hardware thing though, but instead about x86 architecture. You may want to look up mapped device memory.

Comment: @DanielB I'm not sure what you mean. By the way my laptop has an NVIDIA Geforce 840M card which has memory of 2 GB which I don't know if it's included or not. I'm actually very confused since I'm reading a book and lowmem region of book author is same size as his RAM.